# Unable to get offset of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get offset of some elements which is working fine for me. But the problem occurs if element id contains single quotes. It throw an error, e.g, if the element id is whats_next its working fine.
But if id is what's_next if gave me an error.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #What's_Next

....value:null},t.error=function(e){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized exp...
```

Also I don't have access over HTML I can not change the HTML. Do you guys have any solution for this ?

Here is my code:

```
$('.custom-toc li a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(id);
   console.log($(id).offset());
});
```

HTML of element where I am clicking:

```
<a rel="internal" href="#What's_Next">What's Next</a>
```

HTML of element offset element:

```
<span id="What's_Next"></span>
<h4 class="editable">What's Next2</h4>
```

Comment: can you share html as well?

Comment: It is because of the `'` Symbol in your href that you get the error

Comment: The `'` is not a valid character for the `id` attribute so you should inform whoever provides the HTML that they need to fix it.

Comment: no problem here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tnmfvgh/)

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil i have added the html as well,

Comment: try escaping it like this id.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1').

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil i am getting same error in your js fiddle also pls check console.

Comment: See this [http://jsbin.com/muheyot/edit?html,js,console,output](http://jsbin.com/muheyot/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: @GarvitMangal Thanks buddy, it wasn't working also in my case so i have removed # from id.replace and where you are getting offset now it working . Please post this code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape `'` using `replace()`

HTML:

```
    <div class="custom-toc">
   <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#What's_Next">dddfs</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
  <span id="What's_Next">hello</span>
<h4 class="editable">What's Next2</h4>
```

JS :

```
 $('.custom-toc li a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('href').replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1');
  console.log(id);
   console.log($(id).offset());
});
```

Comment: So you basically replace every special character with leading backslash + character... it's like this jquery faq implies: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: i don't know why it stop working in # replace i had to remove # from regex pattern. i hope it wont cause any error in future

Comment: @Nils right but someone who is trying to escaping anything in regex can do that before apply jquery defined characters

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going for the id as attribute approach?

Like this:

```
var id = "What's Next";
var elem = $("span[id="+id+"]");
```

Well I tried, and it doesn't work :) - Cudos to Garvit, he has it right, this is his solution (only simplified):

```
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(id);
  id = id.replace("'","\\'");
  console.log($("#"+id).offset());
```

Comment: not working just now i have tried this getting undefined offset

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it without escaping the quote, although it requires you to remove the hash from the front of the href (and also, using $("*") is slow)

```
$('.custom-toc li a').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
var a = $("*").filter(
    function(index) {
        return $(this).attr('id') == href;
    }
);
console.log($(a[0]).offset());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the `'` symbol inside your div's `id` - You should change

```
<span id="What's_Next"></span>
```

to

```
<span id="Whats_Next"></span>
```

EDIT:

because You can't/don't want to change div's id You are working on an invalid code. You should consider debugging it first to further work.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @Tibrogargan comment I've checked the w3c recommendation and he's probably right:

> id = ID A unique identifier for the element. There must not be
>   multiple elements in a document that have the same id value. Any
>   string, with the following restrictions:
>
> - must be at least one character long
> - must not contain any space characters

Source: [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: i don't have access over html i can't change ids like this , also i don't want to change id with jquery.

Comment: @ofcapl I believe quotes are acceptable in an id in HTML5.

Comment: I've updated my answer - thanks for mentioning this - I haven't realised that now it can be a valid (?) syntax